# babeljs throwing 'unterminated regular expression' in </type> of renderDetails() method

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to write small piece of ES6 React code and compiling it using Babel. I get this error of 'unterminated regular expression'. No clue why this is happening. Needs help.

```
class List extends React.createClass {
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      showList: this.props.showList,
      listType: this.props.type
    }
  }

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      showList: true,
      type    : "ul"
    }
  }

  propTypes: {
    type: React.PropTypes.string;
  }

  renderDetails() {
    var showList = this.state.showList,
        type = this.props.type;

    if (showList) {
      return
        <type>
          {this.props.items.map(function(item) {
            return <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
          })
        </type>
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.renderDetails.bind(this)}
    );
  }
};

React.render(<List type="ul" items={items} />, document.body);
```

[image: Error snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, you want an enclosing () for multi line returns and you don't have the closing } between type type. Should be like this.

```
    if (showList) {
        return (
            <type>
                {this.props.items.map(function(item) {
                    return <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
                })}
            </type>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was one of my dumb mistakes, I guess. I need some rest now.